# In Django, how can I get an instance of the class-based-view that a URI resolves to?

Tags: python, django, uri, resolve

I'm developing a navigation system, and I need to get a `class based view` from a URI that points to it.

Where I'm at now is using `resolve('/path/to/whatever/')` to get a ResolverMatch.  A [ResolverMatch](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#django.urls.ResolverMatch) has a dict item `func`, which links to the `class based view` only as a callable function, not as an object.

`ResolverMatch(func=catalog.views.ThingDetail, args=(), kwargs={'id': '99'}, url_name=thing_detail, app_names=[], namespaces=[])`

What I need is the object as an object, though.  I'm hacking my way through it by using `inspect` to get the `func` method's object, but it seems like there should be a better way.

Comment: So do you want the class object or an instance of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found that there is a property `resolver_match.func.view_class`, and I can just call `resolver_match.func.view_class()` to get an instance of the class-based-view.

Thanks to @schwobaseggl for pointing out that `resolver_match.func` is an object with properties.  It's weird and surprising that an object with the class `function` has properties.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work to get you the view class and an instance thereof if needed:

```
import importlib

rm = resolve('/path/to/whatever/')  # ResolverMatch
module_name = rm.func.__module__  # 'path.to.views'
view_name = rm.func.func_name  #'FooView'

views = importlib.import_module(module_name)
# <module 'path.to.views' from '/path/to/project_root/path/to/views.pyc'>

view_klass = getattr(views, view_name)
# <class 'path.to.views.FooView'>

view_instance = view_klass()
# <path.to.views.FooView object at 0x7fe2219528d0>
```

Note, however, that it is not possible to get the very instance that will be used for a certain request this way because the view class is only instantiated when  `rm.func` - the callable return by `View.as_view()` - is called.

Extract from [implementation of `View`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/base.py):

```
@classonlymethod
def as_view(cls, **initkwargs):
    ...
    def view(request, *args, **kwargs):
        # See: view cls is only instantiated when 'view' is called
        self = cls(**initkwargs)
        ...
        return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
    ...
    return view
```